# Is Synergy safe?

Tags: exploit

I looking for input when using Synergy, http://symless.com/synergy/.  Yes, they have a pro version that enables SSL.  I'm still wondering about keyloggers and network sniffers, I assume that would be still a potential 'risk'.

As well, is there any known exploits for Synergy I should be concerned about?  I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: I used to setup IPsec rules so I can use it securely between computers. However, this is very confusing process. `stunnel` may be easier to use.